# find word and plus sign

Tags: regex

Im trying to find using visual studio regex to find any line which contains at least 1 plus sign and the word enum one or more times.

To be clear: if it contains anywhere a plus sign and the sequence of letters "enum" with anything before, after and in between, it should return it.

Have tried many variations but no success:

\benum.+(?!\w)

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Also, does the order matter?

Comment: Can your line contain anything apart from `enum` and `+`?

Comment: VS 2012, yes, it just needs to contain any number of + AND also the enum word one or more times

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
^(?=.*enum)(?=.*\+).*$
```

Make sure you use multiline mode if your input string spans multiple lines.

---

Matches:

```
enum+
+enum
foobar+enum+barfoo
enumeration +
enumenum+
```

Does not match:

```
enum
+1
en+um
```

---

Explanation:

- `(?=.*enum)` - Checks that the line contains "enum"
- `(?=.*\+)` - Checks that the line contains a "+"
- `.*` - Matches the entire text of the line
- `^` and `$` - Makes sure the entire line is matched

Comment: I'm using VS2012 but unfortunetly this isnt working, I may be doing something wrong but I just opened find and replace, ticked reg expressions and searched without results when there should be lots. Maybe I wasn't clear that before, after and between plus signs and enum words there can be any characters, does that change the reg expr?

Comment: @Rivers It should be working. Can you give an example of something that should match and doesn't?

Comment: @Rivers In the find tool, you should also turn off "Match whole word" if it's on, since it will prevent it from matching properly.

Comment: I'm sorry kendal, I didn't read properly your "Does not match section". I've always run away from complex reg expressions and I just realized I also didn't give you complete information, when I meant the word enum, I should have said, it should have return it as long as it contains "enum". so if it contains anywhere a plus sign and the sequence of letters "enum" with anything before, after and in between, it should return it

Comment: @Rivers I've edited it so that it matches "enum" as part of a longer word.

Comment: That's working beautifully, I can now see how far I was from the answer and glad this was not one of those days I was stubborn to figure it out by myself for hours before asking for help!